# Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR) Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Paciente' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy trabajando con laravel 5.5 me funcionaba todo bien hasta que agregue dos clases mas de la que ya estaba trabajando(paciente), me muestra la pagina de `create` pero al agregar y que dirija a la otra se cae
el error es el siguiente

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
>   (E_ERROR) Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Paciente' not found

Mi archivo `web.php`

```
Route::resource('paciente', 'PacienteController');
```

---

Mi controlador

```
public function index()
{
   $pacientes=Paciente::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(10);
    return view('paciente.index',compact('pacientes')); 
}



public function show($id)
{
    //
  $pacientes=Paciente::find($id);
    return  view('paciente.show');
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Es posible, que el nombre del controlador no sea el mismo que el nombre del archivo y/o el nombre de la clase.

dice que no encuentra

```
App\Http\Controllers\Paciente
```

Y la ruta tiene `PacienteController`, entonces, verifica eso.

Answer (score 0):

> El error ocurre por que estas usando un modelo denominado **Paciente**, pero no estas importando dicho archivo a través de su *namespace* al inicio de tu controller, lo solucionas así:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Paciente;
```

Con la sintaxis de **`use App\Paciente`** ya queda disponible a nivel de tu controller

Si necesitas usar uno o varios modelos dentro del mismo controller, bajo la misma estructura anterior, debería verse de este modo:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Paciente;
use App\OtroModelo;
use App\OtroModelo;
```

Comment: No entiendo el voto negativo acá, si bien puede tener alguna mejora la respuesta, pero la veo relativamente bien.